# VPN Packet structure in different VPN implementations

Tags: vpn

In order to understand different VPN technologies I tried to write down how a single HTTP packet could look like using each implementation.

SSH VPN

```
HTTP | TCP | IP | Ethernet ||| SSH | TCP | IP | Ethernet
```

OpenVPN bridged mode

```
HTTP | TCP | IP | Ethernet ||| OpenVPN | TLS | TCP | IP | Ethernet
```

OpenVPN routed mode

```
HTTP | TCP | IP ||| OpenVPN | TLS | TCP | IP | Ethernet
```

IPSec tunnel mode

```
HTTP | TCP | IP ||| IPSec Auth Header | IP | Ethernet
```

PPTP

```
HTTP | TCP | IP | PPP ||| GRE | IP | Ethernet
```

L2TP

```
HTTP | TCP | IP | PPP ||| L2TP | UDP | IP | Ethernet
```

It is based on information from different sources and I'd like to ask three questions:
1) Are the diagrams correct?
2) Are PPP and Ethernet interchangeable?
3) Is OpenVPN 'TCP over TCP' as implied by the diagrams above?

Comment: PPP and ethernet are two different layer-2 protocols. Either can be used to encapsulate upper-layer protocols. Ethernet is a broadcast protocol, but PPP (Point-to-Point Protocol) is not. Both have pros and cons.

Comment: @RonMaupin which in the context of the question means that my diagrams can use either. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I would say yes, they are correct for some variants of these VPNs.

2) Ron Maupin already pointed out a difference. PPP is sometimes used to insert authentication like in PPPoE or with some proprietary IPsec extensions using IKEv1.

3) OpenVPN is best used with UDP because TCP over TCP is not a good idea. This [article from Olaf Titz](http://sites.inka.de/bigred/devel/tcp-tcp.html) explains why. Usually you only use TCP over TCP when UDP isn't possible because some firewall on the way between the VPN gateways won't allow it.